# JUnit4-Serenity: Create an executable jar with all required dependencies and run the tests standalone

Tags: java, docker, maven, serenity-bdd

Please help solving the below:

Create an executable jar file of a Maven Java Project which only consists of JUnit4-Serenity tests and run it on command line.

1. Serenity-JUnit4 Maven Java Project - used only to run tests.
2. It only consists of test classes and each test class has an annotation @RunWith(SerenityRunner.class).
3. Currently I am executing all the test using the mvn command as below with couple of input parameters "appName" and "testENV":

   mvn clean verify -DappName=test -DtestENV=integration
4. Reference project - https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-junit-starter - running using Maven.
5. I am doing this to dockerize it by adding the created jar to a base image which consists of some required root CA.

Comment: Can you please share the code produced so far and what is it that is not working, please? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply ... I have added the repo in GitHub. Please take a look. https://github.com/raj-fords/serenity-junit-starter

Comment: Please let me know if more information is required. Thanks.